# Dynamic script loading by arbitrary name

Tags: javascript, load

I would like to load script dynamically by enering hash string in the browser:

```
var query = this.param.query; 
// This is a hash string. Example: http://domain.com/#!man
files.run("jsfolder/"+query+".js", function() {query.init()}); 
// or files.run("jsfolder/man.js", function() {man.init()});
```

But code above returns:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function 1.js:98
(anonymous function)
(anonymous function)
script.onload
```

How to solve this issue?
Thanks.

P.S

My man.js file:

```
var man = {
    init : function(){      
       //do stuff   
    }
}
```

Callback function (executes after script loads):

```
function() {query.init()}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what environment you're operating in, but this should do the trick:

```
var header = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],
    script = document.createElement("script"),
    query = this.param.query;

script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = "jsfolder/" + query + ".js";

header.appendChild(script);
```

Essentially you create a script element and append it to the head. This will load and execute any JavaScript inside the specified file.

As far as I know, there is no `files.run` function.

Comment: Please check my updated answer. I know how to load the file but I don't know how to execute it. Thanks!

Comment: @user889349 Stick `man.init();` at the end of your file and it will execute as soon as it's loaded. Or you can call `man.init()` in your callback function.

Comment: I can't use man.init() I'm trying to use: dunamically query.init()